# How to create transition table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two table Movie and Actor

```
@Entity
@Table(name="movie")
@Data
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer MovieId;
    ......

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "actorId", referencedColumnName = "actorId")
    private Actor actor;
}





   @Entity
    @Table(name = "actor")
    @Data
    public class Actor {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
        private Integer actorId;
        private String firstName;
        private String  lastName;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "actor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)


   private List<Movie> actorMovies = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Now in MySql database i have two table but I need transiet table movie_actor. Now I have Movie table and column actorId and insert only one id. I want to have relation that One Movie have many Actors.

Comment: Ues  `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "MOVIE_ACTOR",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "MOVIE_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ACTOR_ID")
    )`

Comment: you mean a JOIN TABLE. Any JPA docs would tell you that